# Spatial queries with PostgreSQL on AWS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have some data in  PostgreSQL which I am exporting to Amazon RDS service.

Is it possible to use PostGIS extension in AWS?
(And will I need the mandatory `geom` column or I could run queries with only latitude and longitude values?)

Comment: Note that the name "geom" is just a convention, not a requirement; you could name the column `chocolate_cake_with_grapefruit_juice` if you were so inclined.

Comment: Oh yeah, I should mentioned is the geometry column mandatory, which I have found out by now that it is required to run spatial operations, despite having lat long values. Yes I understand geom is just a naming convention, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will be able to use PostGIS with RDS. See Amazon's user guide on [Working with PostGIS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.PostGIS).

It appears to be the full, unmodified extension, so I would assume it operates just like a non-cloud installation. You'll still need a geometry column in order to run spatial queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. Let me try it out

Comment: Im facing some connection issues with AWS, waiting for support from their team. Meanwhile I just wanted to know if I will be able to import existing postgres databases into aws server. The reverse is possible I know. Could you help please Alex?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to import. See their help files here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html

Comment: Alex any idea about this : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/334091/import-table-to-aws-postgres-instance-from-pgadmin-local-host

Comment: I've done this, and taught workshops with it. It's easy. Just enable the extension and away you go...